# Wrapping code in helper function verbatim leads to borrow error

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I created a helper function `get_node()` for a common pattern, but for some reason it leads to borrow errors, but when copy pasting its contents it does not. I've marked the problematic lines with comments:

```
type NodeMap = HashMap<i32, Node>;

pub trait IdGenerator {
    fn gen(&mut self) -> i32;
}

pub struct Tree<'a> {
    active: i32,
    nodes: NodeMap,
    generator: &'a mut dyn IdGenerator,
}

impl<'a> Tree<'a> {
    pub fn create_sibling(&mut self) {
        let active = self.nodes.get(&self.active).unwrap(); // <-- THIS WORKS
        // let active = self.get_node(self.active);            // <-- THIS FAILS

        let mut node = Node::new(self.generator.gen(), active.parent);
        // [......]
    }

    fn get_node(&self, id: i32) -> &Node {
        self.nodes.get(&id).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Uncommenting and commenting the two `let active...` lines leads to the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self.generator` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/tree_new.rs:35:34
   |
34 |         let active = self.get_node(self.active);
   |                      ---- immutable borrow occurs here
35 |         let mut node = Node::new(self.generator.gen(), active.parent);
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ------------- immutable borrow later used here
   |                                  |
   |                                  mutable borrow occurs here
```

The error messages makes sense, but what I'm confused on is why the same borrowing logic doesn't apply to the original code without the helper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line immutably borrows `self.nodes` for the lifetime of `active` (which is the current block scope):

```rust
// immutably borrows self.nodes
let active = self.nodes.get(&self.active).unwrap();

// mutably borrows self.generator
self.generator.gen();

// no overlap, no problem ✔️
```

Later in the same scope you mutably borrow `self.generator` but `self.nodes` and `self.generator` don't overlap so there's no problems.

However, this line immutably borrows **all** of `self`, which includes `self.generator`, for the lifetime of `active` (which is the same block scope as before):

```rust
// immutably borrows self
let active = self.get_node(self.active);

// mutably borrows self.generator
self.generator.gen();

// compiler error:
// immutable borrow of self overlaps with mutable borrow of self.generator ❌

// ...

// this function signature says: as long as the returned
// reference is live the entire struct is immutably borrowed
fn get_node(&self, id: i32) -> &Node {
    self.nodes.get(&id).unwrap()
}
```

Now since **all** of `self` is immutably borrowed, when you try to mutably borrow `self.generator` later, the immutable borrow of `self` and the mutable borrow of `self.generator` overlap and you get a compiler error.

Unfortunately this is a known limitation of Rust. There's no way to "enrich" the type signature of your helper function to communicate to the Rust compiler that the immutable borrow depends specifically only on `self.nodes` and not on all of `self`. However there are people who are interested in adding this to the language and you can track their progress in the [Partial Borrowing](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1215) issue on the Rust RFCs repo. The typical workaround is to [split borrows](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html) but your helper function is so tiny I don't think that approach applies here and your best bet would be to just get rid of the helper function and continue writing the logic inline.